# How to verify URL using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, url, assert, assertion

I am beginner in python/selenium and would appreciate yr help with following:
I run a test with Social Media icons on website:

1. to check if SM icons exist and if their links are active, which is fine
2. to check if links of icons are correct (provided vs outcome) - here I have problem how to define

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import urllib
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pytest

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://www.poland4weekend.com/')

link_FB = "https://www.facebook.com/Poland4Weekend/"

time.sleep(1)
button_accept_cookies = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/button[1]')
button_accept_cookies.click()
time.sleep(1)
link = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="bgLayers_comp-jsugpnao"]/div[1]')
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(link).perform()
driver.get_screenshot_as_file('footer_screenshot.png')

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="dataItem-jsugpnbn-comp-jsugpnbl"]/a')
button_fb = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="dataItem-jsugpnbn-comp-jsugpnbl"]/a')
button_fb.click()
assert button_fb is not None
print ("Link FB is active")
```

The problem is when I used:

```
URL = self.driver.current_url
self.assertequal('https://www.facebook.com/Poland4Weekend/', URL)

if self.driver.current_url == link_FB:
    print("FB link is correct")
else:
    print("FB link is incorrect")
```

Is there any better method to verify provided links vs link on website???

Answer (score 0):

### Assert in Python

Assertion is the boolean expression that checks if the statement is True or False. If the statement is true then it does nothing and continues the execution, but if the statement is False then it stops the execution of the program and throws an error. The assert keyword helps in achieving this task.

---

### Flowchart of Python Assert Statement

[image: Flowchart of Python Assert]

---

### This usecase

To assert/validate the url you can use the following lines of code:

```
URL = self.driver.current_url
assert 'https://www.facebook.com/Poland4Weekend/' == URL,"URLs are different!"
```

---

### Usecases

There can be two results as follows:

- If the boolean expression is *True*, the program execution proceeds.
- If the boolean expression is *False*, an *`AssertionError`* is raised.

---

### tl; dr

[assert](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/statements/assert.html#assert)